# Angular CLI Build Options

Tags: angular, cordova, angular-cli

I love Angular CLI and use it for all my Angular projects. But every now and again I run into a use case that the tremendously bad official docs don't help with. So at the risk of bundling too much into one question, here are my most pressing questions:

1. How does one configure build targets and what are they used for? The official docs tell you how to specify them and distinguish between build *targets* and build *environments*, but leave the rest up to your imagination. I think it determines a few flag values and unflaggables (new word) like using `UglifyJS`.
2. `ng build --app` "Specifies app name or index to use." That little sentence there is the sum total of all documentation. I have a case where it would be handy to have one `index.html` for one environment and another `index.html` for another. I thought this may be it, but it seems not. Does anyone know how to use this, or to conditionally supply a different `index.html`?
3. I have configured two additional environments and can read those values at run-time. Fabulous. What I want to do is include an additional script to deploy for my extra environments. So the normal `dev` and `prod` act as always, but `devextra` and `prodextra` deploys an extra file (a bit like conditionally adding something to `scripts` in `.angular-cli.json`.

Points 2 & 3 are for integration with another tool. My present workaround is a manual edit of index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a good answer for items 2 & 3. Number one is still a mystery.

Here is an example `.angular-cli.json` showing how to do it:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "project-name"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "somescript.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }, {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../completely/different/folder",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "otherindex.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "somescript.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.extra.dev.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.extra.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  /* These are empty for brevity */
  "e2e": {},
  "lint": [],
  "test": {},
  "defaults": {}
}
```

So this is a little big and most of it is duplicated, so allow me to give you a tour.

1. The `apps` array actually has two objects in it. Normally there is only one and I'm not sure when multiple app support was added, but that is what the `--app` command line is for. So `ng build --app 0` uses the first object for configuration and `ng build --app 1` uses the second one. The same with `ng serve`.
2. I was able to provide a different output path, a different index.html and even a completely different set of `environment` files. Also, notice the two configurations deploy two different (and totally believable) script files. There is actually so much you can vary here, it's impressive.

A few gotchas:

1. Don't mess with `environmentSource`. It then seems to just default to the `dev` environment from the first configuration.
2. A few flags don't seem to work so well. I think `deployUrl` only works on the command line and `baseUrl` can't be specified in config at all. There may be others.
3. While they allow you to change `root` I really can't see why you wouldn't just do a completely different app. It probably isn't wise to stretch this past its design envelope.

My current thinking is that I'll use a single `.angular-cli.json` with multiple configurations and then create batch files to wrap my `ng build`/`serve` calls.